# Deploying angular/ionic app on cloud foundry

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push ionic PWA on cloud foundry, as cloud foundry uses node.js buildpack , at first I was getting start command not found issue . To solve this I have added : "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve" in package.json. I have also added manifest.yml file with following:
applications:

```
name: CfTestApp
memory: 256M
command: ionic-app-scripts serve
```

After this when i try command "cf push CfTestApp" , I get error as : "ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused" if I try to push it without healthcheck with command "cf push CfTestApp -u process".
The application runs but if i try to access it using the routes then it shows the error as : "502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request."
Note: The application works fine in local host.

I would like to understand what different has to be done to make ionic application run and accessible from cloud foundry. As i tried a normal node.js app on CF it worked fine. I am stuck with this, please suggest what can be done. Thank you!

Comment: Is your application looking at the `$PORT` environment variable and listening for connections on that port?  Most of the time when I see the behavior you're describing it's because the app is not listening on the correct port.  As a side note, if all your Node app is doing is serving up files, you should look at using the staticfile buildpack instead.  That will use Nginx to serve up your application files and is going to be more efficient.

Comment: @DanielMikusa : Thank you ! it was a useful information .